# How to query for city name as well as length of the smallest city name from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

My code is this but gives error, don't know why. Please help!

```
select city, 
       min(length(city)) 
from station 
group by length(city)=min(length(city)) 
order by city asc;
```

Comment: And the error is... ?

Comment: Error is : Invalid use of group function

Comment: Maybe explain what you are trying to accomplish with that group by statement?
Looks like you are mixing up a GROUP BY and a WHERE Statement

Comment: Thanks for the insights I finally got the code right:                                               select city, min(length(city)) as smallest
from station
group by city order by smallest asc limit 1 ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the city with the shortest name, you can simply `order by` and `limit`:

```
select city, char_length(city) city_length
from station
order by city_length
limit 1
```

This returns just one row. On the other hand, if you want to allow bottom ties, then you can filter with a subquery, like so:

```
select city, char_length(city) city_length
from station
where char_length(city) = (select min(char_length(city)) from station)
```